# Unity 2D. Null Refrence Exception problem

Tags: unity-game-engine

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>   CombatBehavior.FixedUpdate () (at Assets/Scripts/CombatBehavior.cs:92)

---

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>   CombatBehavior.FixedUpdate () (at Assets/Scripts/CombatBehavior.cs:94)

```
    gameObject.GetComponent<DamageDeal>().DealDmg();

    gameObject.GetComponent<DamageDealToSkeleton>().DealDmgToSkeleton();
```

---

Hello, im having troubles with NullRefrence Exception. Could anyone explain me what am i doing wrong. As a disclaimer i want to tell that two lines there were working but i wanted to improve some of my code, so i ended up ctrl + z-ing everything what did a mess. But unfortunetly its gone... Unity still telling me that there is Null value.

I was trying to solve it by setting something like this:

```
        GameObject player = GameObject.Find("Player");
    DamageDeal damageDeal = player.GetComponent<DamageDeal>();
    damageDeal.DealDmg();

    DamageDealToSkeleton damageDealToSkelet = player.GetComponent<DamageDealToSkeleton>();
    damageDealToSkelet.DealDmgToSkeleton();
```

in my Game Object Player -> CombatBehaviour.cs -> FixedUpdate.
It's a matter of life and death, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the scripts are still on the object after you did the ctrl+z deal?
Is everything correctly spelled? Case-sensitive.

With what you have presented i feel like this is the only thing we have to go by.
Triple check it all :)

Comment: it looks like you were kind of right - now i don't have null reference (for now) but... i have two types of enemies, could you look at my code and tell me where the difference is? I have no idea for now what i going on. In advance, thanks you for your time.

https://gist.github.com/KeelanPL/4f7964f79fa85ed10abfcc8f1edb6c18

there are two both of them (DamageDeal is workin, the second one isn't)

Comment: you don't get a null refrence anymore, but what is the current problem now then?

Comment: Also. instead of having damage script for each enemy, consider having just one and give each enemy a tag and use that tag to loop through inside the script.

Comment: In my DamageDealToSkeleton : Monobehaviour there is function, called DealDmgToSkeleton(), and when i attack that skeleton, i got refrence that it just read but didn't do damage its only reading my first Debug.Log. As you can see in code my sample

Comment: Given that knowledge you know for a fact that attackPosSkelet.gameObject.activeSelf isn't true. Try to do some debugging to see where it goes wrong (e.g try to log the attackPosSkelet, the attackPosSkelet.gameObject and the attackPosSkelet.gameObject.activeSelf just to see if everything is set correctly). Before the if obviously

Comment: Soooo... You said triple check... well i'm blind moron... Emm it was attack from tutorial from one Blog... and they adviced to set it for Game object which will activate when it reach a point in animation. I changed that name by accident... rest is... ughh... anyway. Thank you for solving my NullRefrence problem ^^. Sorry if you wasted time.

Comment: Haha no problem :) That happens a lot. Glad I could help :)